# I want to display a gif in the sidebar of my google spreadsheet when a button is clicked

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sidebar in my google spreadsheet. It contains two buttons. On the click of the "Retrieve Invoice" button I would like to run a function "retrieveCurrentRow()" and also display a gif until that function is done running. If that is not possible, I would be happy with just displaying the gif until the sidebar is closed.

This is what I have so far to open the sidebar:

```js
function currentRowSidebar()  {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  if (sheet.getName() != "InvoiceRecord")  {
var goToInvoiceRecord = ss.getSheetByName("InvoiceRecord");
ss.setActiveSheet(goToInvoiceRecord);
} 
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```

Then the html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
    <p> 
    Put your cursor on the line of the invoice you want to retrieve and then click the "Retrieve Invoice" button.</p>
    <p> 
    Close the sidebar when you are done. </p>
    <p>
    <input type="button" value="Retrieve Invoice" onclick="google.script.run.clickAction(); google.script.run.retrieveCurrentRow()"/>
    <input type="button" value="Close Sidebar" onclick="google.script.host.close()" /></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And finally the "clickAction()" function which is where I think the gif display code would be.

```js
function clickAction() {
var img = UrlFetchApp.fetch(https://c4a54d10381f750e81dcc323aed21e2c95725815.googledrive.com/host/0Bwyqwd2fAHMMallsNkNOV0RfcTg/wait_progress.gif)/wait_progress.gif"></div>');

  
}
```

The best case would be for the image to appear under the buttons in the sidebar, and then disappear when the "retrieveCurrentRow()" function has finished running. The last step of that function is an alert to let the user know the function is complete. It would also work if the gif could pop up in a dialog box of some kind. I would also accept any other suggestions. The "retrieveCurrentRow()" is quite extensive and takes about 20 seconds to run. Even though I know what it is doing and how long it will take, I find that I am extremely tempted to click the button again instead of waiting. I know it will drive my user crazy if there is not something that let's them know the progam is working. :)

I have really exhausted my experience at this point and don't know where to go next or if this is even possible, and since I can't find anything of the sort in my internet searches, it leads me to believe this is not probable. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The function "retrieveCurrentRow()" ends with an alert. I found out that an alert will automatically close an HTML modal dialog. So I put in a showModalDialog() html with the animated gif and no button. It will run until the alert closes it. Of course, the user could close it early with the "x" but I put text in there to let them now that the dialog will close when the operation is complete. This is what I ended up with.

Open the sidebar:

```js
function currentRowSidebar()  {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  if (sheet.getName() != "InvoiceRecord")  {
var goToInvoiceRecord = ss.getSheetByName("InvoiceRecord");
ss.setActiveSheet(goToInvoiceRecord);
} 
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```

Then the html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
    <p> 
    Put your cursor on the line of the invoice you want to retrieve and then click the "Retrieve Invoice" button.</p>
    <p> 
    Close the sidebar when you are done. </p>
    <p>
    <input type="button" value="Retrieve Invoice" onclick="google.script.run.clickAction(); google.script.run.retrieveCurrentRow()"/>
    <input type="button" value="Close Sidebar" onclick="google.script.host.close()" /></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the click action to open the html modal dialog:

```js
function clickAction() {
 var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sampleHtml')
 .setWidth(300)
 .setHeight(300);
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Retrieving invoice.');
 }
```

Then the html with the gif:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
<style>
   h2 { color:red; font: 20px bold verdana, helvetica, sans-serif; }
   p { font: 14px normal verdana, helvetica, sans-serif; }
   #btn { float:right; border-radius: 15px; }
</style>

<div>
<h2>Please be patient.</h2>
<p>The action you are performing may take a while.</p>
<p>This dialog will close when the retrieval is complete.</p>
<p><img src="http://chimplyimage.appspot.com/images/samples/classic-spinner/animatedCircle.gif" alt="Progress Indicator" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And finally, the last little bit of the "retrieveCurrentRow()" function that contains the alert:

```js
  var results = ui.alert('Invoice Retrieval Complete', 'Continue to the retrieved invoice?', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
```

It doesn't really matter what the previous parts of the "retrieveCurrentRow()" function are as long as the alert is at the end of the function. This is really a work around, and there may be a better way to do it, but it worked! I'm happy.